# How to GPG-sign a commit when reverting in Magit?

Tags: magit, gpg

When I commit in Magit, I have the option to "Sign using GPG". But when I revert a commit in Magit, I don't see this option. Is it hidden? If so, how do I activate signing in that context? Otherwise, does the feature not exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just added `--gpg-sign` to the revert popup.

Since it sounds like you are signing all commits anyway, you might also just set the Git variable `commit.gpgSign`.

And you can always add your own actions and arguments to a popup. In this case this would have worked:

```
(magit-define-popup-option 'magit-revert-popup
  ?S "Sign using gpg" "--gpg-sign=" 'magit-read-gpg-secret-key)
```

For more information about that, see [Customizing existing popups](https://magit.vc/manual/magit-popup/Customizing-existing-popups.html)

Comment: Setting `commit.gpgSign` solved my problem more generally. Now I don't even need the feature from Magit. :)